# Are there any other style types besides CSS for HTML?

Tags: css

```
<style type="text/css">..</style>
```

From the above HTML, I think there should be, but I've never seen it, is there?

Comment: Good question! I was just wondering that myself the other day.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Netscape 4 (only) supported [Javascript Style Sheets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Style_Sheets).

Answer (score 7):

As of HTML5, you don't need to supply a `type` any more, since there are no other relevant style types. The same goes for `script`.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, not in HTML, but XML (and consequently XHTML) support XSL stylesheets using XML style sheet definitions:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="foo.xsl" title="XSL Rules"?>
```

It's worth mentioning because the same [PI](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi) will allow you to attach CSS style sheets to XML documents as well.

Answer (score 3):

[There are lots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stylesheet_languages), but CSS is pretty much it as far as browser support goes.

Answer (score 1):

The way [less](/questions/tagged/less) is added to a web page makes it look as if it were a separate kind of style sheet.

`<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />`

Of course it is just Javascript making a css on the fly.